# Round an NSTimeInterval object's value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, nstimeinterval

How can I round a value of an `NSTimeInterval` object?

For example I have an `NSTimeInterval` object called `duration` and its value is `1459` (24.31667 minutes), how can I round it to 25 minutes?

Thank you!

Comment: An `NSTimeInterval` is just a double.  Use standard functions for rounding.

Comment: @Avi I've tried to use `round()` function, but it doesn't seem it does anything

Comment: Sounds like you just want `ceil(duration/60.0)` (if you want it rounded up), use `round` otherwise.

Comment: If you want another time interval, it will be `ceil(duration/60.0)*60.0`

Comment: @originaluser2 Thank you! That's worked!

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimeInterval` is nothing but a `typedef` of `double`. You can always use the library methods built for `double` or `float` for that matter. For your specific requirement I would suggest you use `ceil(timeInterval)` method and in order to avoid the fraction part, you might want to cast it like this:

```
long result= (long) ceil(duration);
```

Comment: Wrong answer. NSTimeInterval is in seconds.

Comment: @KarimBenhmida Of course it is in seconds but it can have floating numbers as well. OP is asking about how to round of `NSTimeInterval` values which is exactly what I answered.